# Why did MS-DOS choose the percent symbol to designate variables?

Tags: history, ms-dos

I couldn't find anything but is there any reason for choosing `%` over `$` like in *nix shells?

Comment: Not only MS-DOS uses `%` instead of `$`, but the syntax is different. In *nix, the dollar sign is a [sigil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_%28computer_programming%29), and the percent sign in MS-DOS is more like a magic quotation mark, as variable names must be enclosed in percent signs to be interpolated, rather than just preceded by a percent sign (e. g. `%PATH%`). This avoids the need to have another magic character, like parentheses to indicate the variable name boundary, like in `$(foo)bar`. Then it makes sense to use a new character to indicate its new semantics.

Comment: @LeoB. Nitpick: In Bash, `$(foo)` means "run command `foo` and insert its `stdout`put into the command whereas (in POSIX shell also) `${foo}` means "value of variable `$foo`.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I was thinking about the Makefile syntax where the parentheses are mandatory.

Comment: ICL George III also used % but in a completely different way.  There were 26 variables and you could do indirection using multiple % signs. The GEORGE equivalent of C's **A would be %%%%%A.

Comment: One might ask why Unix shells chose "$" when there was already an example of "%" being used for substitution-type operations, in C printf formats.

Comment: The question implies that '$' is a better choice **because** Unix had already used it. I don't see anything to support that. In general, if you're looking for a funny character to use for something, you just pick what seems reasonable from what is so far unused and therefore available.

Comment: @another-dave In fact, I think `$` is a **poor** choice, especially as `$<number>` has a special meaning in Unix shells. What if I just want a string containing some number of US dollars?

Answer (score 15):

Because it was already reserved for batch file command-line parameters.

Early DOS versions (1.x) did not support environment variables at all. They did, however, support batch files and parameter substitution using the `%n` syntax ([source](https://github.com/microsoft/MS-DOS/blob/04a3d20ff411409ab98474892b2bb1713bde0f7f/v1.25/source/COMMAND.ASM#L683-L692)). The character `%` was already reserved for that purpose, and already had to be escaped as `%%` in batch files; it made sense to re-use it for variable substitution, as the two features are quite similar.

The `$` character, on the other hand, was already in use in names of temporary files, for example in EDLIN ([source](https://github.com/microsoft/MS-DOS/blob/04a3d20ff411409ab98474892b2bb1713bde0f7f/v2.0/source/EDLIN.ASM#L560-L573); the public source code is from the 2.0 version of DOS, but the [binary in the `v1.25/bin/` directory](https://github.com/microsoft/MS-DOS/blob/04a3d20ff411409ab98474892b2bb1713bde0f7f/v1.25/bin/EDLIN.COM) contains equivalent code, offset +0xd0 in the binary); subsequent DOS releases added more such uses. If the `$` character were used for variables and the user wanted to delete a leftover temporary file with such a name (or, especially, if they wanted to have a batch file do it), the `$` character would have to be escaped, which would be inconvenient (not to mention it would pose a slight backwards incompatibility). I am under the impression that Microsoft wanted to avoid adding more escape sequences to COMMAND.COM syntax, from the fact that for example they outright banished `<`, `>` and `|` from file names when pipes were introduced.

Of course, that in turn raises the question why `%` was used for batch file parameters instead of `$`, like in the equivalent CP/M functionality provided by the SUBMIT command.  Batch files are supported in MS-/PC DOS 1.x, but apparently not in 86-DOS 0.3; the [manual](https://web.archive.org/web/20160409042609/http://www.patersontech.com/dos/docs/86_Dos_usr_03.pdf) makes no mention of it.  So it appears the functionality was added sometime between those two versions; this is confirmed by the [86-DOS license agreement between Microsoft and Seattle Computer Products](https://web.archive.org/web/20230508073022/https://antitrust.slated.org/www.iowaconsumercase.org/011607/0000/PX00001.pdf), which (on page 8) mentions “SUBMIT facility comparable to CP/M” as one of the improvements to 86-DOS that Microsoft requested from SCP.  We might guess that EDLIN was already using `$` for temporary files before batch files were introduced, and indeed, if we disassemble the version of EDLIN found on the even earlier [86-DOS 0.1 floppy image](https://archive.org/download/86-dos-version-0.1-c-serial-11-original-disk), we find this:

```
        ; RBIL #01378, 5Ch:
        ; first default FCB, filled in from first commandline argument
        mov         si, 0x5c       ; +0x002d  be5c00
        mov         di, 0x5fb      ; +0x0030  bffb05
        mov         cx, 9          ; +0x0033  b90900
        rep movsb                  ; +0x0036  f3a4
        mov         si, 0x528      ; +0x0038  be2805
        movsw                      ; +0x003b  a5
        movsb                      ; +0x003c  a4

        ; INT 21 - DOS 1+ - DELETE FILE USING FCB
        mov         ah, 0x13       ; +0x003d  b413
        mov         dx, 0x5fb      ; +0x003f  bafb05
        int         0x21           ; +0x0042  cd21

        mov         al, '$'        ; +0x0044  b024
        mov         di, 0x5fb+9    ; +0x0046  bf0406
        stosb                      ; +0x0049  aa
        stosb                      ; +0x004a  aa
        stosb                      ; +0x004b  aa

        ; INT 21 - DOS 1+ - DELETE FILE USING FCB
        mov         ah, 0x13       ; +0x004c  b413
        int         0x21           ; +0x004e  cd21

        ; INT 21 - DOS 1+ - CREATE OR TRUNCATE FILE USING FCB
        mov         ah, 0x16       ; +0x0050  b416
        int         0x21           ; +0x0052  cd21
```

So presumably `%` was chosen for that reason.  But to be sure you’d probably have to ask Tim Paterson; otherwise your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: Answer can be improved: at some point ^ was added to escape. When was that?

Comment: No earlier than in Windows NT, maybe OS/2. No version of MS-DOS supported it.

Comment: In many DEC systems, '$' was used as a reserved-to-DEC character in symbol names, as a primitive way to separate the namespace into DEC-use and customer-use. The 'softies would be familiar with this, and I think that's how '$' is used in DOS etc.

Answer (score 14):

By using a `\` as path separator, they needed a different marker for control character encoding, and did choose `$` which in turn meant that the variable marker need to be another one, which turned out as `%`.

So by choosing `%` instead they could have kept `$` for variables, but then again is the parser structured a bit different as it allows concatenated strings, thus needing a finishing marker at the end of named variables. So they didn't and the rest is history :))

---

I'm not complete so sure right now about the full implications, but `$` is used at least in three different ways on the MS-DOS command line and in batch.

- Expand a batch variable to a full path name with `%~$PATH:<varnumber>`
- Defining special content for the [PROMPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Command_prompt) command like date and time as in `prompt $d $t$g`.
- Code the escape character in parameters as `$e` like `echo $e[0m` for screen reset.

Especially the does give the lead here, as marking special characters in Unix is done via a backslash `\`, which in DOS marks a directory level. MS had to use `$` instead, so `\e` became `$e`.

Further, but way later (DOS 5)

- [DOSKEY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOSKEY) used `$` to indicate special functions in macro generation.

---

Surprisingly, its predecessor CP/M did use `$` as variable indicator as well as marker for special meanings in some commands (like privileges in `STAT`).

In CP/M batch files are run with the `SUBMIT` command, which will read a file (standard ending `.SUB`) and feed each line to the OS, after replacing variables marked with `$`. DOS has this feature build in and treats `.BAT` files like programs.

Comment: In bash they resolve the ambiguities by adding brackets `${var}`

Comment: CP/M's CCP doesn't give `$` any special meaning.  `STAT` and `SUBMIT` are transients (separate programs) that interpret command-line parameters or strings in the input themselves.

Comment: @phuclv Remember that *bash* is a Johnny-come-lately; that strategy is of a far more ancient lineage.

Comment: `/` was used for options in existing programs so `\` was most likely chosen to avoid breaking those.

Comment: The `%~$PATH:<varnumber>` syntax is only supported by `cmd.exe`, it was never available in DOS. And the bit about ‘control character encoding’ makes no sense. COMMAND.COM has no escape syntax for command lines (other than `%%` for the `%` character, and the syntax of the `PROMPT` variable).

Comment: So the use of `-` changed the use of `/`, which changed the use of `\ `, which changed the use of `$`, which changed the use of `%`.  [There's a hole in my bucket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_a_Hole_in_My_Bucket), dear Liza, a hole.

Comment: @DrSheldon: I wonder if there would have been any difficulty using colons as a path specifier (as was done with the later Macintosh), and saying that relative paths are those that either don't contain any colons, or start with either a colon or dot-colon.

Comment: it certainly gives the impression that they tried to impose their standards with \, %, damn drives, CRLF, and failed against Linux/Unix  and now we're stuck with both standards... Truly visionnary. Fortunately they didn't invent their flavour of regexes too...

Comment: "Impose their standards" seems a bit biased. Why should the designers of system A constrain their choices because of what the designers of system B might have done?  Why not complain that Unix did not follow the pre-existing CRLF standard used on DEC systems?

Answer (score 1):

I can't know for sure but I suspect one of the reasons was that `$` was used as the string terminating character in the standard DOS "print string" API ([`int 21h ah=9h`](https://fd.lod.bz/rbil/interrup/dos_kernel/2109.html#2601)), a convention apparently [inherited from CP/M](http://seasip.info/Cpm/bdos.html).

Comment: [Why did DOS use dollar-terminated strings?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/7638/1981)