# Why did DOS use dollar-terminated strings?

Tags: ms-dos, assembly

According to a few tutorials I am seeing, DOS used dollar-terminated strings to write to the terminal. This seems to [also be documented here on `INT 21H`](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah02).

```
AH = 09h - WRITE STRING TO STANDARD OUTPUT
Entry: DS:DX -> '$'-terminated string
Return: AL = 24h
Notes: ^C/^Break are checked
```

You can see this from the code in [this tutorial here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e0bMDc0lWAE&index=9&list=PLajZfknhluUSY6weDgx3xYuRsaXUwU8mh) What was the reason for going with dollar-terminated strings rather than NUL-terminated strings like C?

Comment: That comes from CP/M.

Comment: [why is the string in function 9 terminated by a dollar sign?](https://forums.techguy.org/threads/why-is-the-string-in-function-9-terminated-by-a-dollar-sign.907478/)

Comment: Please note that all other strings in DOS (like file names) are NUL-terminated.

Comment: That is not actually true, M. Rosenau.  Command tails in the PSP are terminated by Carriage Return, for starters.

Comment: You tag "MS-DOS" - but I think you really mean the other versions of DOS which MS-DOS was based on.  ie - do you want a "it was like that in the version that MS-DOS was based on" or do you want a "it was like that in the previous versions because ..."

Comment: Why would he not tag MS-DOS?

Comment: @MartinRosenau "All" other strings is a bit of a misnomer, especially since you mention file names; FCBs use a fixed-length (11 bytes) field for the file name, for one.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

The short answer is that DOS was designed to be similar to CP/M, and drawing a quote from [here](http://dosmandrivel.blogspot.com/2007/08/is-dos-rip-off-of-cpm.html):

> While 8-bit programs could not run on 16-bit computers, Intel
>   documented how the original software developer could mechanically
>   translate an 8-bit program into a 16-bit program. Only the developer
>   of the program with possession of the source code could make this
>   translation. I designed DOS so the translated program would work the
>   same as it had with CP/M – translation compatibility. The key to
>   making this work was implementing the CP/M API.

Or course this brings up the question as to why CP/M used the dollar sign.

[This discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.os.cpm/GrVgI0jk1HY%5B1-25%5D) says CP/M got the idea from DEC, which used the [RAD50](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEC_Radix-50) character encoding.  With only 40 characters (50 octal), you only have uppercase, digits, space, period, dollar, and percent.

> Both CP/M and RT-11 are evolved from earlier DEC OS's, most notably
>   OS/8 (on the PDP-8) and DOS-11 (on the PDP-11).  The most obvious
>   feature of all of these OS's is the presence of "PIP"

So DEC probably chose dollar because it didn't have many options, CP/M got it from DEC, and DOS got it from CP/M.

Comment: I'm really impressed by the RAD50 information. I'll mark this answer as chosen if no one else has anything to do add. It looks like you went down a good rabbit hole from DOS to CP/M to find that.

Comment: I'm skeptical that RAD50 is what's going on here. RAD50 was used in specific places such as file names and extensions where a small subset of ASCII was acceptable. But RAD50 has only about three special characters, and that's not enough for generic strings. Strings have to be able to handle the full ASCII character character set.

Comment: That's a great discussion you linked, by the way. Tim Shoppa, who is reliable, suggested it might go back to mainframe data conventions from the 1970s. And here's an example -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMS-2_(programming_language)#Program_structure -- a mainframe language in which every statement line is terminated by a dollar sign. There's no way I know of to connect the dots to CP/M though. And it also seems like this ancient convention may also explain why a dollar sign at the end of a regular expression is an assertion of end-of-line.

Comment: It could also explain why in BASIC a dollar sign at the end of a variable *name* denotes a string type -- if it was already thought of as a string terminator.

Comment: You might also go back to TECO.  Teco was a text editor originally from MIT, that made its way to DEC in the 1960s.  Commands like insert and search were followed by a text string.  This text string was terminated by an escape character.  This escape character was echoed as a dollar sign.

Comment: RAD50, at least on PDP-11 operating systems, never needed a terminator. It was used in fixed-length contexts, e.g., the name of a file in FILES-11 was 6 characters = 2 words in RAD50.  If you wanted a shorter name, it would be padded with spaces.  RAD50 also cropped up in symbol tables, and $ was a frequent initial character ('reserved to DEC').  Contrariwise, there was a lot of precedent in various DEC operating systems for ASCII strings terminated by a zero byte (ASCIZ). Many assemblers provided ASCIZ directives. TOPS-10 had a UUO 'OUTSTR' to print an ASCIZ string.

Comment: Don't you mean RT-11 never heard of DOS-11

Comment: Nevertheless, there was a DOS-11.  It was a very early PDP-11 system.  Here's the Wikipedia entry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEC_BATCH-11/DOS-11

Comment: Maybe not RAD 50 but SIXBIT, which had no control characters and therefore no NUL?

Answer (score 16):

So, what about the last part of the question, why not use nul as c?
As shown in [an earlier answer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/7640/10565), MS-DOS was influenced by CP/M, CP/M was influenced by DOS/11 on PDP-11 and that was an extension of OS/8 from PDP-8.

OS/8 used a character set called DEC Radix-50.
After checking the link about the [RAD50](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEC_Radix-50) character set, the answer why OS/8 didn't use nul to terminate strings is quite simple. nul is Space in that character set.
Considering that apart from letters and digits you only had 3 punctuation marks ".", "%" and "$" you had to choose one.
The question remaining is why they choose $ and not %.

Besides that, as commented below, C did not exist when the PDP-8 was constructed, so it could not have influenced the choice of string terminator.

Comment: That's an interesting hypothesis.

Comment: But you are also speaking as if C always existed but it didn’t really get popular outside of Bell Labs until the mid to late 70’s.

Comment: This answer fails to demonstrate a connection between paper tape and MS/PC-DOS version 1.

Comment: The PDP-8 predates the C language by a long way - C was first targeted at the PDP-11.

Comment: I'm not convinced that radix50 encoding was actually used to any significant extent in OS/8. Its not a system I've ever used, but looking through the manuals it seems ASCII was used almost exclusively (packed 3 characters into each pair of words). I also don't see any evidence that $ was ever used as a terminator in rad50 strings; given the purpose which is usually described for it (for compressing identifiers to make hashtable keys) then fixed width strings are much more likely, and such strings would usually be space padded rather than have a terminator applied to them.

Comment: Another data format apparently used for strings in OS/8 was "six bit stripped ASCII" (packed two characters per word and padded with zeros). This format was produced by the system assemblers (of which two were provided, PAL8 and SABR) TEXT directives.  This is probably what's called "DEC SIXBIT" in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six-bit_character_code#Examples_of_six-bit_ASCII_variants)

Comment: Also note that null terminated strings are not C's invention ... C actually inherited that convention from the DEC assemblers that its early compilers targeted (the PDP 11 assembler, for instance, had a directive `ASCIZ` to produce null terminated strings), so it seems unlikely Kildall wouldn't have been exposed to the idea even though he stsrted working on the first versions of CP/M before C was well known.

Comment: Verson 1 of unix was for the PDP-7,  which predated the PDP-8.  The port to the PDP-11 was the motivation for C.

Comment: The `%` vs. `$` decision is rather easy. It's save to assume that PDPs at that time where rater used in engineering ans universities than accounting - the later being the only area where a `$` sign would be more useful to be printable than a `%`.

Comment: @WalterMitty: Yes Unix started in 69 on the -7 in B and moved in 70 to the newly-available -11 creating C, but -8 and -7 had both existed since 65 (and their predecessors -5 and -4 even earlier).

Answer (score 15):

It's worth noting that CP/M was written originally in the PL/M-80 programming language (also developed by Gary Kildall)  (source [here](http://www.cpm.z80.de/source.html) )

The [PL/M-80 Manual](http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/intel/PLM/9800268B_PLM-80_Programming_Manual_Jan80.pdf) on page 11 states that

> The character set used in PL/M is a subset of both ASCII and EBCDIC character sets.  The valid PL/M characters consist of the alphanumerics
>
> A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
>
> a b c d e f g h I j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
>
> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
>
> along with the special characters
>
> = . / ( ) + - ' * , < > : ;
>
> and the blank characters
>
> space  tab  carriage-return  line-feed
>
> If a PL/M program contains any character not in this set, the compiler may treat the character as an error

That's 80 characters.

Interestingly there is no mention there of $ at all - yet on page 15 it is listed as a character that "may be freely inserted between the characters of a constant to improve readability".

I can't say whether or why this might have affected the decision to use $ as the string terminator for function 15 in CP/M, especially since page 16 is explicit that "character strings are denoted by printable ascii characters enclosed by apostrophes" which doesn't limit it to the same character set as the code body.

I can say from personal experience that function 15 was almost never used, and CP/M / CP/M-86 / MP/M / Concurrent DOS / CDOS /… assembler programmers pretty well invariably used subroutines containing loops that called function 2, usually using either a byte count or a null terminator.