# Why did some old MS-DOS games lack the ability to exit them?

Tags: ibm-pc, ms-dos, gaming

While playing around in DOSBox-X, I'm reminded of some DOS games which appear to entirely lack the ability to exit/quit/close them.

One prime example of that is "Paratrooper" from 1982. I've tried every key on the keyboard, including <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>. Nothing makes the damn thing close. I have to kill the entire emulator to make it go away. Is this really how it was designed? If so, why?

All the sane DOS games either allow you to just press <kbd>Escape</kbd> to instantly get dumped back to the DOS prompt (oftentimes with a snarky remark about how boring it is and how you should continue playing the fun game instead), or at least allow for exiting the game through its menu system.

But *Paratrooper* does not. And it's not the only one. It's also not even an `EXE`, but a `COM`. Is this somehow related to its inability to exit?

Comment: It should be mentioned that in that time period, rebooting and power-cycling a microcomputer throughout the day was expected.  Many of the machines had a prominent RESET button on their keyboard for that very reason.

Comment: "But Paratrooper does not. And it's not the only one. It's also not even an `EXE`, but a `COM`. Is this somehow related to its inability to exit?" No, it isn't. Besides you should really look at the file magic to determine whether it is an MZ executable or a flat .COM-style executable. That's what DOS does. It allows either filename extension for either type of executable. Only the presence of either an "MZ" or "ZM" signature (both work) indicates a non-flat executable.

Comment: Alt-X and Ctrl-Q.

Comment: @ecm Windows nowadays still does that. You can rename any EXE files to COM and it'll still work, or save any random text files beginning with MZ then run from cmd and it'll show some invalid format error

Comment: This is not specific to MS-DOS either; Commodore 64 games and ZX Spectrum are also like that. Just take control over the whole machine, and you can forget the operating system even exists.

Comment: This is also how console gaming platforms worked for a long time. Insert game, start console, then turn the console off or reset it with a different game inside.

Comment: Alt+F4 was never a shortcut in DOS - it first arrived in Windows (at least since 3.1)

Comment: @JimNelson I seem to remember it being possible to down a NetWare 3 or 4 server and exit back to DOS (`DOWN` and `EXIT`). Is that incorrect?

Comment: @StephenKitt I didn't think so, but when I Googled for `NetWare DOWN EXIT` I found it described on the OS/2 Museum.  He knows better than me, so apparently that is the case! https://www.os2museum.com/wp/netware-2-x-notes/  Shame on me, I wrote NetWare drivers for three years, you would think I'd recall that...

Comment: @JimNelson By default `EXIT` will return you to DOS but there is a `REMOVE DOS` command that kicks DOS out of memory (meaning NetWare looses access to C drive and any DOS disk drivers for CD-ROMs, etc) and gives that memory to netware. If you've run `REMOVE DOS` then `EXIT` will reboot the system as there is no DOS resident in memory to exit back to.

Comment: Ah-ha!  Perhaps that's what I was remembering.

Comment: The shortcut to exit the program was `Ctrl`-`Alt`-`Del` which at that time instantly rebooted the machine.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: The game "Tawala's Last Redoubt" for the Apple II (very early game) has a "Save and quite" function, but in the manual it indicates that if one doesn't wish to save, the game should be exited by flipping the power switch--"works every time".

Comment: Regarding first appearance of ALT+F4, I believe it was used as part of IBM CUA before Windows started using it.

Answer (score 137):

[Paratrooper](https://www.mobygames.com/game/pc-booter/paratrooper) was originally a “PC booter”. All [PC booters](https://www.mobygames.com/browse/games/pc-booter/) run without DOS or any other operating system¹ — to start them, you would insert the floppy into the drive, and switch the computer on (or reboot it). There was nothing for such a game to exit *to* — once you’d finished playing, you’d switch the computer off, or reboot it from a different floppy (or from the hard drive, if you had one). As pointed out by [ssokolow](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/1920/ssokolow), this is similar to how many other micros were used at the time, and continued for a long time on home computers such as the Atari ST.

In most cases, people converting PC booters to DOS executables wouldn’t add an exit feature — it would likely have been quite complex to do so. “Ripping” a booter to an executable already involves making a number of changes in many cases: some PC booters were copy-protected, so that has to be defeated, and many would write to their floppy, which also would have to be disabled (or re-implemented). As [Jim Nelson](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/4222/jim-nelson) explained in a comment, rebooting wasn’t at all unusual in DOS days², so adding an exit feature wouldn’t have been high on anyone’s to-do list!

However, Paratrooper is well-behaved — it doesn’t overwrite anything it shouldn’t —, so you can add an exit feature to the game yourself: download [`HBREAK`](http://www.dreamlandbbs.com/filegate/bfds/bfds/hbrk55.zip), and run it before you run the game. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> (followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> in some environments) will return you to the DOS prompt. This works fine in DOSBox and DOSBox-X.

You can also exit the game if you use [an image of the original booter version](http://web.archive.org/web/20080530020004fw_/http://retrograde.trustno1.org/orion.htm), instead of the DOS conversion: there’s a piece of software, [Flopper](http://oldskool.org/pc/flopper), which can “boot” booter games on top of DOS, and it allows you to exit back to DOS. If you’re interested in how it goes about this, it comes with extensive documentation and complete source code.

*The* reference for PC booters was [Retrograde Station](http://web.archive.org/web/20090720234640/http://retrograde.trustno1.org/index.html); the site disappeared long ago, but most of it is archived, including many images of games.

Another project to look at if you’re interested in booter games is [Digger](https://www.digger.org/); this is a remaster of a booter game, and its documentation includes various titbits about booters in general.

As far as the executable extension (`.COM` or `.EXE`) goes, it doesn’t have any impact on whether the program can exit or not. The extension itself [doesn’t distinguish between executable formats](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/14523/79), but booters do tend to be ripped as binary images rather than MZ-type executables: whichever technique is used to dump the executable, it’s easier to store it as a headerless binary than work out the MZ header. Most booter games are small so they wouldn’t run into [the size limits associated with the format](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/14520/79) either.

---

¹ Games don’t need much in the way of operating system services, and everything needed by typical DOS games of the era, other than file access, was provided by the BIOS and easily re-implemented with direct hardware access anyway. File access wasn’t always necessary in the days of floppy disks — many booter games would “own” their disk, so they didn’t have to care about files, and any disk access they cared about (*e.g.* to store a high-score table) could be done through the BIOS or by directly programming the floppy-disk controller. Counter-examples include [Sid Meier’s Pirates!](https://www.mobygames.com/game/214/sid-meiers-pirates/cover/group-42398/cover-385257/) which required a DOS-formatted floppy disk to save games to.

² So much so that later versions of QEMM even implemented a “fast reboot” feature — it allowed DOS to be rebooted without actually resetting the computer and going through the system’s POST again.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129015/discussion-on-answer-by-stephen-kitt-why-did-some-old-ms-dos-games-lack-the-abil).

Comment: On machines like the TRS-80 and original Mac, having a game boot from disk was often an extra layer of copy protection. There was no operating system and therefore the data on the disk was not formatted as any publicly documented file system.

Comment: In a sense, a booter *is* an operating system. An operating system that does nothing but play the one game.

Comment: I'm surprised that later booter games didn't exceed 64KB. They can by definition fill all the RAM.

Comment: @Joshua Wizardry 4 is one PC booter which required 128KiB of RAM, there may have been others. Wizardry 4 isn’t available as a DOS conversion. (I haven’t checked whether it contradicts my statement re. binary sizes.)

Comment: Wizardry 1 was written using ucsd pascal which could be considered a booted.  I do not know if wizardry 4 was implemented that way too.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen yes, Wizardry 4 was written using UCSD Pascal as well.

Comment: @Acccumulation In a sense, a skateboard *is* a car. I would rather say both operating systems and booter games are kinds of software that run directly on the hardware. A minimal booter would boot into an infinite loop but I wouldn't also call that a minimal operating system. There was a guy who published a YouTube video recently on how he wrote his own operating system when all he did was write a self-booting game. I'm 100% certain I didn't have a collection of hundreds of OSes for my Speccy and Amiga (-:

Comment: The first version of Pirates! by Microprose was created as a PC booter. The savegame could be saved on a second floppy disk, which had to be pre-formatted with a FAT12 file format under DOS before.

Comment: Thanks @Coder, I’ve corrected that part of the answer.

Answer (score 30):

If a program hooks or disables all interrupts, and never invokes any DOS or BIOS functions, it may use all of RAM following the last enabled interrupt vector (typically the keyboard vector at address 0x00024-0x00027) in whatever manner it sees fit, without regard for what portions of RAM might have been reserved for use by DOS or BIOS functions.  If a game included the ability to exit, it would need to determine what areas of memory DOS or the BIOS might be using and ensure that it doesn't disturb them.  If there is no way of exiting other than to reboot, then the amount of memory available to the game will be greater, and the game won't have to worry about the possibility that a machine might have enough memory to meet the game's requirements but some of it is reserved.

Comment: Wasn't much of the upper memory area including the memory in which the BIOS resided read-only? The video memory obviously could be written as well, but I'm pretty sure that at least the BIOS area could never be used and overwritten by any program. That was at least one reason why the 640k limit was so hard to overcome.

Comment: @Schmuddi the BIOS uses RAM as well, the [BIOS data area](https://fd.lod.bz/rbil/memory/bios/index.html), *e.g.* for the keyboard buffer.

Comment: @StephenKitt: If the game takes over all interrupts and doesn't chain to any of the BIOS routines, no BIOS code will get to execute until the system is rebooted.

Comment: @StephenKitt: Many of these games wouldn't plan on using anything past the first 128K-256K.  If one wanted to a game to run on a 128K system, leaving DOS in memory would cut substantially into the amount of memory available for the game.

Comment: @supercat I know, I’m not disagreeing with anything you wrote, only Schmuddi’s comment.

Comment: @supercat and Paratrooper was designed for PCs with only 48K of RAM (which reinforces your point) — see https://www.mobygames.com/game/pc-booter/paratrooper/cover-art/gameCoverId,733171/

Comment: I never coded at this level on the PC but I'd be pretty sure that "never invoking DOS or BIOS" functions is an exaggeration. Surely you could use them to bootstrap if you wanted and then from a certain point start overwriting anything anywhere?

Comment: @hippietrail: I meant that once a program is loaded, it reaches a point *after which* it never uses DOS or BIOS functions.

Comment: @hippietrail: Once the BIOS has been used to set up a CGA screen mode, storing data to addresses in the range 0xB800:0 to 0xB800:0x3FFF will display it; observing keystrokes is a little trickier, but IIRC can be done by reading I/O addresses 0x61 and 0x60 to detect them, and writing address 0x61 to acknowledge them.  Sound uses another couple I/O addresses, and many games didn't do anything other than show graphics, play sound, and watch for keystrokes.

Answer (score 13):

Back then, the operating system was much less powerful than you are used to today.

MS-DOS was a *disk* operating system. It primarily took care of the *disk* (floppy disks, mostly), including reading, writing and executing files, and handling directory structures. Sure, it had a few other functions which would wrap around lower level features of the system, but not too many. It did provide the command line interface and a lot of individual small programs - e.g. to copy files and such - but those aspects are irrelevant for the question at hand as a game would use none of those.

The other important system component back then was the BIOS (basic input output system) which an application could use for, well, text input and output - if the application had no particular performance requirements and preferred an easier API instead of low level access to the devices. BIOS text processing incurred a very much noticeable performance overhead, and generally limited what you can do a lot.

Especially iIn the later days of the 286, 386, 486 and with the advent of more memory, when paging or memory virtualization became more frequently necessary, there were added subcomponents for memory handling, which could be started or configured separately (see [Upper Memory Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_memory_area) or [DOS Memory Management](https://www.vogonswiki.com/index.php/DOS_memory_management) for nice overviews and links to more information).

Aside from these system components, many programs, and certainly most if not all graphically intensive games, talked to the hardware directly. They had direct control over all aspects of the screen (including intricate timings in the phases where the electron beam moved back between lines, or from the bottom to top border), and the keyboard. Sometimes even direct or low-level access to the floppy drive (bypassing DOS), for copyright protection purposes. There was no preemptive multitasking like in every general purpose OS today - there simply was no "power" in the system which could influence the running program that much.

Speaking of which, there was always *one* running program. It would even be far-fetched to call it "process" in our modern meaning; there were none of the features we associate with processes today (priority, time scheduling, ownership of particular resources, separate user/kernel-level permissions etc.), although DOS did keep track of some of the resources and could reserve them for programs loaded at the same time...

... to be used, amongst others, for a type of application called TSR ("terminate and stay resident programs"), which meant that you could start small utilities which would stick around, and would usually intercept keyboard interrupts - so they could do some action on the press of a button, even if another program was currently active. This worked, mostly, but usually not very usefully while in a game which did fancy stuff with the screen. There was no way for a TSR to sanely take control, modify the screen, and restore everything to the previous setting. Of course one could try, but it was always a hack, nothing at all like today. There were no system-level video drivers which could do the state recovery, and so on.

If a program exited on ESC, that was purely a convention. Alt-F4 or other standard key combinations did not exist. Figuring out which keys a game used at all was always part of the fun, especially if you had a decentralized backup copy of a game without the manual...

Comment: Do you have any examples of “complicated and incompatible subcomponents for memory handling, which could be started or configured separately from both DOS and BIOS”? Also, while processes under DOS did mean much less than in current, multi-tasking OSs, there was process ownership of particular resources. And your last paragraph is incorrect, see `HBREAK` in my answer.

Comment: Thanks @StephenKitt, I have integrated your points.

Comment: Hah, I've not heard the euphemism "decentralized backup copy" before, but have fond memories of racing to guess the controls for a flight simulator (from which the startup screen had been removed) before the plane crashed.

Comment: The restriction in your latest edit, “... to be used for a type of application called TSR”, isn’t warranted: resource ownership was also useful for programs running other programs, starting with `COMMAND.COM` ;-). It’s mostly based around [the PSP](https://fd.lod.bz/rbil/interrup/dos_kernel/2126.html#table-01378), used for example in [MCBs](https://fd.lod.bz/rbil/interrup/dos_kernel/2152.html#table-01628). This is how [service 0x4C](https://fd.lod.bz/rbil/interrup/dos_kernel/214c.html) could find the memory to free and files to close on program exit.

Comment: @StephenKitt, this answer is going to be a reference documentation for DOS. :) I've defused my previous edit with a further one.

Comment: None of this actually answers the asked question.

Answer (score 8):

One possible explanation could be: because the game has corrupted or leaked the memory or resources (video modes, sounds) and you'd need a reboot to get back the system in a clean state anyway, so better not give a false hope to the user.

It's not as easy as it seems to cleanly exit from a program, specially on old OSes.

Comment: As this was a booter game, it basically was the OS. Just like you can't quit the DOS operating system and warm boot into same or another OS because there is no need to do that, there is also no need to exit from a game booted to run without OS.

Comment: @Justme You actually can ‘quit’ DOS, in a way: you can enter DEBUG and invoke interrupt 0x18/0x19, or launch a boot loader of another OS that supports being run from within DOS (like GRUB4DOS or LOADLIN). I seem to recall there is even some code in the DOS kernel itself to support doing the former.

Comment: @user3840170 You can invoke the bootstrap int 19h, but it is not a preferred reboot method - generally it would not know about how to shut down DOS or anything running below it gracefully. A loader for another OS like Linux that is run from DOS would generally understand enough about DOS and the hardware to disable interrupts and relocate itself to somewhere so Linux kernel can be safely loaded and executed. Some memory managers and disk caches can hook int 19h to get a warning to shut themselves down gracefully, like flush caches to disk.

Answer (score 8):

#### Because reset times were negligible

Having to reset the PC is only an issue if the PC takes a long time to boot afterwards.

Assuming you had the memory check turned off in your BIOS, the time from powering on your PC to the DOS shell running was single-digit seconds. There really wasn't any inconvenience to it.

Comment: Somewhat agree. Reset times were certainly shorter for most home micros at the time (e.g. Apple II reset was sub-second), but the original IBM PC and frankly many PCs through the late 1980s did a memory test which took 5-20 seconds depending on how much memory you had installed. That being said, some games would let the Ctrl-Alt-Del reset work to get out which may avoid the memory check, but I seem to remember at least a few games that you needed to physically power cycle the machine which would cause the check to happen.

Comment: PC's power-on test was really annoyingly long.  An interesting feature I learned about a few years ago, though, which really surprised me is that the BIOS looks for a special diagnostic code from the keyboard connector and can be made to skip launch code supplied via the keyboard port if the diagnostic code is received.  Since the BIOS was published, I find it interesting that nobody designed and built a fast-boot gizmo that daisy-chained into the keyboard port.

Comment: Another reason why rebooting is more of an issue on modern computers is that you're likely to have other programs running simultaneously and a reboot would interfere with whatever they are/were doing.  With a single-tasking OS, that problem wouldn't come up (TSR's notwithstanding)

Answer (score 2):

It has already been mentioned in the other answers that most games were designed as PC booters and therefore no DOS was loaded and in order to have as much RAM as possible for the game available.
But there is another important point that hasn't been mentioned yet:

Another reason was that the first PCs didn't have a hard drive anyway, so it was completely normal to swap out the floppy disks and boot from them directly the next game. If you had to first insert the DOS boot disk to boot from DOS and then swap the disks again for the game disks in order to then start the game, then that would have taken even longer and the first PCs weren't exactly fast.

For this reason, it made sense to boot straight into the game, thus the game didn't need an exit function. First loading an operating system like DOS and then starting a game from DOS only made sense when hard drives became a standard part of the PC.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know to which games this might apply, but I'm sure that some programmers simply did not consider an exit feature to be important.  Back in the early DOS days, your program may not have been the product of a team, but the output of a single programmer with an idea.  Some were self-taught and had not programmed long enough to recognize that some of their users would expect a clean exit.  Even if they did recognize this, if it was not an important program feature for their own taste, why would they bother?  They got this neat thing they want to share and maybe make a buck, so get it out there!

Comment: I imagine it's probably easier to make a game if you're able to quit out of it and change things.

Comment: and being able to quit is also important for debugging

Comment: @knol and phucly, In a case where the programmer is writing a self-booting program that self-boots, bypassing DOS, then including a clean exit would be tantamount to a reboot anyway.  Assuming the development system had a hard drive, reboot time to DOS would be short.  A reason to do this is if you were targeting a small system with just 64k or 128k of RAM.  You might also be using a development system that makes target builds for a different machine, but would still provide debug hooks.

Comment: @phuclv and Knol, Even if your development machine has sufficent RAM for DOS, the development environment, and your game, the low-end machines you plan to support may not.

Comment: I disagree. If you're writing a program directly for DOS, it's easy to return to DOS with a MOV AH, 4Ch followed by an INT 21h. You just have to be careful when writing your program that you don't write into DOS' memory area.
Laziness or ignorance is definitely not the reason for installing an exit routine. The reason was, as already mentioned above, that the game was designed as a PC Booter without first loading DOS as the operating system in order to have as much of the little RAM as possible for the game.

Comment: Another reason was that the first PCs didn't have a hard drive anyway, so it was completely normal to swap out the floppy disks and boot from them directly the next game. If you had to insert the DOS boot disk first to boot DOS, it would have taken longer to start the game.

Comment: @Coder Back when DOS machines had no hard drives, they didn't have DOS function 4Ch either so you could not call it. It took a bit more effort than that to exit cleanly back to DOS.

Comment: @Justme not really, DOS 1 [supported clean exits using `RET` or `INT 20h`](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/16896/79).

Comment: @StephenKitt Sure and also the JMP 0 which basically should execute int 20h, but that wasn't the point. The DOS function 4Ch can be executed anywhere and this method did not exist until DOS 2.X, and the older methods require the CS to match the address of PSP.

Comment: @Justme I already said, that the machines didn't have a HD. But returning to DOS does nothing have to do with the existence of a HD. MS-DOS 2.0 had the 4Ch function, MS-DOS 1.0 had the 20h function inherited from CP/M. The only difference is that the first allows a return value in the AL register, the other does not.

Comment: @coder Back in the day other machines had "booter games" so people made them for PC too and they worked without DOS as there was not enough memory for both DOS and the game if you had minimal memory. When later such booter games were converted with loaders to programs startable from DOS, the booter still did not expect a DOS and expected to use memory as if it was booted by BIOS, so it might have overwritten DOS and certainly the original booter game would have nowhere to return and if it did it would not be DOS anyway. So games that took full control of the machine can't return to DOS.

Comment: @Justme You obviously didn't understand who I was contradicting and what I was contradicting them about. Nobody said that PC booters didn't take full control of the resources. So what's your point please? Your comment is completely off topic and echoing me.